# How to wrap multiple groups of LIs within a string with ULs in php

Tags: php, html

I get data (strings with some html) from different sources I can't influence. The strings contain (but are not limited to) `LI` elements that are visually grouped - but miss parent `UL` elements. I need to wrap the groups of `LI` tags with a `UL` tag.

This works fine if there is only one group of `LI` elements within a string. I can easily use `DOMDocument`, search the `LI` tags and wrap them with a newly created `UL` tag. Unfortunately there can be multiple groups and the separation of the groups isn't defined - but is always some kind of text or a html tag. It's easily to recognize the groups as a human :)

So logically speaking I would need to find an opening `<li>` as the starting point of a group and a closing `</li>` that isn't followed by another opening `<li>` as the end point, ignoring all white spaces.

An example source string could be (it doesn't always have new lines and isn't always that pretty):

```
Some text
<strong>Some other text</strong>
<li>Element A1</li><li>Element A2</li>
<li>Element A3</li>
Text that separates group A from group B
<li>Element B1</li>

<li>Element B2</li> <li>Element B3</li>
<li>Element B4</li>
<strong>Element that separates group B from group C</strong>
<li>Element C1</li>
<li>Element C2</li>
Text can follow.
```

The desired result would be

```
Some text
<strong>Some other text</strong>
<ul>
  <li>Element A1</li><li>Element A2</li>
  <li>Element A3</li>
</ul>
Text that separates group A from group B
<ul>
  <li>Element B1</li>

  <li>Element B2</li> <li>Element B3</li>
  <li>Element B4</li>
</ul>
<strong>Element that separates group B from group C</strong>
<ul>
  <li>Element C1</li>
  <li>Element C2</li>
</ul>
Text can follow.
```

I was thinking about using regex (I know, usually not the best idea for html). But here I don't know how to recognize the ending `</li>` (or  etc.) that is followed by anything other than a white space or another opening `<li>` (or < li > etc.)

I could also remove all white spaces between a `>` and a `<`; maybe the world would be a little bit easier then. But even then I don't know how to "include" an opening LI as a valid following element within a group and exclude everything else.

**EDIT:**

My current bad (almost naughty) regex solution looks like this:

```
$txt = preg_replace('/(\>)\s*(\<)/m', '$1$2', $source_text);
$txt = preg_replace("/\<\/li\>(?!\<li\>)/", '</li></ul>', $txt);
$txt = preg_replace("/(?<!\<\/li\>)\<li\>/", '<ul><li>', $txt);
```

It works fine until it doesn't. For example, if some of the `LI`-blocks already have a wrapping `UL` :)

All my `DOMDocument` approaches failed due to the fact that plain text isn't treated as a child node. That means that I am able to find the `LI`s and check if their siblings are `LI`s or not and then wrap them all together in a `UL` if the latter case applies. But if the `LI`-groups are separated only by some text without any `HTML` tag, all the `LI`s are treated as direct siblings without any separation.

Comment: Would make more sense to check if the next/previous sibling of the current LI element you are on, is still a LI, or something else …

Comment: I suppose that best solution is to parse the HTML string through PHP XML DOM Parser (https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_xml_dom.asp) and apply some algorithm, like balanced parentheses problem.

Comment: My best advice for you is to organize your data source. By doing so, you will be able to just loop through, and each collection of `li` will be easier to control/manipulate

Comment: Would be great if I could. Unfortunately the data sources are 3rd parties I can't influence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution I could think of would be:

1. Wrap each `<li>...</li>` into `<ul>...</ul>` tags by replacing every `<li>` with `<ul><li>` and every `</li>` with `</li></ul>`.
2. Remove all `</ul>` which are followed by `<ul>` ignoring all whitespaces and line breaks in between.

Code should be as simple as:

```
// first step
$txt = str_replace('<li>', '<ul><li>', $source_txt);
$txt = str_replace('</li>', '</li></ul>', $txt);

// second step
$txt = preg_replace('/<\/ul>\s*<ul>/', '', $txt);
```

If there might be `<li>` already wrapped by `<ul>` as mentioned by @Pilan in comment, you could add a third step which removes `<ul>` followed by another `<ul>` and `</ul>` followed by another `</ul>`:

```
// third step
$txt = preg_replace('/<ul>\s*<ul>/', '<ul>', $txt);
$txt = preg_replace('/<\/ul>\s*<\/ul>/', '</ul>', $txt);
```

Comment: Sometimes, life can be so simple.

Comment: Nice one, but if there are already `<ul>?` you would end up with `<ul><ul><li>` in the text, you sill have to check for `<ul>` preceding `<li>` so i guess regex ist still the best choice. - `/(?<!<ul>\s*)<li>/g` replace with `<ul><li>` and `/<\/li>(?!\s*</ul>)/g` replace with `</li></ul>` - so a combination of all solutions here - **good teamwork**! :D

Comment: @Pilan: Added a third step which addresses these edge cases.

Comment: I've just replaced all `<ul>` and `</ul>` with a `<oldul>` placeholder-tag (to keep a separation of groups), continued with steps 1 and 2, and removed the `<oldul>` tag afterwards. I guess, the result is the same with some minor speed differences.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't use regex for parsing html (we've all seen **that** SO answer :-P )

So here's a solution that breaks the text down line by line:

```
<?php

function isLi($line) {
    return strstr($line, '<li');
}

$text = 'Some text
<strong>Some other text</strong>
<li>Element A1</li><li>Element A2</li>
<li>Element A3</li>
Text that separates group A from group B
<li>Element B1</li>

<li>Element B2</li> <li>Element B3</li>
<li>Element B4</li>
<strong>Element that separates group B from group C</strong>
<li>Element C1</li>
<li>Element C2</li>
Text can follow.
<li>Hello, nothing follows this</li>';

$array = explode("\n", $text);

$html = '';
$previousWasLi = false;

foreach ($array as $line) {
    if (empty($line)) {
        continue;
    }
    if (isLi($line) && $previousWasLi == false) {
        $html .= "<ul>\n";
        $html .= $line ."\n";
        $previousWasLi = true;
    } elseif (isLi($line) && $previousWasLi == true) {
        $html .= $line ."\n";
        $previousWasLi = true;
    } elseif (!isLi($line) && $previousWasLi == true) {
        $html .= "</ul>\n";
        $html .= $line ."\n";
        $previousWasLi = false;
    } elseif (!isLi($line) && $previousWasLi == false) {
        $html .= $line ."\n";
    }
}

// if the last line was an li, we need to close the ul
if ($previousWasLi) {
    $html .= '</ul>';
}

echo $html;
```

This outputs:

```
Some text 
<strong>Some other text</strong> 
<ul> 
    <li>Element A1</li>
    <li>Element A2</li> 
    <li>Element A3</li> 
</ul> 
Text that separates group A from group B 
<ul> 
    <li>Element B1</li>  
    <li>Element B2</li> 
    <li>Element B3</li> 
    <li>Element B4</li> 
</ul> 
<strong>Element that separates group B from group C</strong> 
<ul> 
    <li>Element C1</li> 
    <li>Element C2</li> 
</ul> 
Text can follow. 
<ul> 
    <li>Hello, nothing follows this</li> 
</ul>
```

You can see it working here https://3v4l.org/kmfee

Comment: Thank you for the effort :) I should have mentioned that the string isn't that pretty formatted all the time. It arrives from different sources. With and without line breaks; with new lines within a <li></li> or without; and so on. But I'll make some experiments with tidying it beforehand - maybe that ends up as a sufficient solution.

Comment: Ah, I was going to ask you that too lol! Anyway, best of luck, let me know how you get on!

Comment: @antesoles if that's the case, then you need to update your question to reflect the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You can "almost-pretty format" the code 1 step before using @delboy1978uk solution using this code:

```
<?php
// $code_to_split is your code
$text = implode("\n<li", explode('<li', implode("</li>\n", explode('</li>', $code_to_split))));
function fnIsComplete($totest){
    return (strpos(' '.$totest, '</li>')>0);
}
// use @delboy1978uk solution over $text
// add a param $iscomplete = false as 2° line
// inserting a validation rule to know if a line is <li ...  >  </li> complete
// add a test at } elseif (!isLi($line) && $previousWasLi == true) { block
} elseif (!isLi($line) && $previousWasLi == true) {
    if($iscomplete ){
        $html .= "</ul>\n";
        $html .= $line ."\n";
        $previousWasLi = false;
    }elseif(fnIsComplete($line)) {
        $html .= $line ."\n";
        $html .= "</ul>\n";
        $previousWasLi = false;
    }else{
        $html .= $line ."\n";
    }
}
// and when you set $previousWasLi = true; you set also $iscomplete
$previousWasLi = true; $iscomplete = fnIsComplete($line);
```

Answer (score 1):

Best is to split the procedure into smaller steps.

- find all `li` tags
- group them based on the text between them
- inject the `ul` tags

It gives you way more flexibility, like fixing missing closing tags.

```
class LiFormatter{
    public $html;
    private $lis;
    private $groups;

    public function __construct($html){
        $this->html = $html;
        $this->lis = [];
        $this->groups = [];

        $this->findNextLi(0);

        if(count($this->lis)==0)
            return;

        $this->determineGroups();
        $this->wrap();
    }

    private function findNextLi($offset){
        $html = $this->html;

        $start_index = strpos($html,'<li>',$offset);

        if($start_index===false)
            return;

        $end_index = strpos($html,'</li>',$start_index+4);
        $next_index = strpos($html,'<li>',$start_index+4);

        if($next_index!==false && $next_index<$end_index){
            // handle missing closing tag
            $this->insertAt('</li>',$next_index);
            $end_index = $next_index;
        }

        $this->lis[] = ['start' => $start_index, 'end'=>$end_index+5];

        $this->findNextLi($end_index);
    }

    private function determineGroups(){
        while(count($this->lis)>0){

            $last_li = array_shift($this->lis);
            $group = [$last_li];

            while(count($this->lis)>0){
                $current_li = $this->lis[0];
                $str_between = substr($this->html,$last_li['end'],$current_li['start']-$last_li['end']);

                if($this->isSeperating($str_between)){
                    break;
                }else{
                    $group[] = $current_li;
                    array_shift($this->lis);
                    $last_li = $current_li;
                }
            }

            $this->groups[] = $group;
        }
    }

    private function wrap(){
        $offset = 0;

        foreach ($this->groups as $group) {
            $first_li = reset($group);
            $last_li = end($group);

            $group_start = $first_li['start'];
            $group_end = $last_li['end'];

            $this->insertAt('<ul>',$group_start + $offset);
            $offset += 4;

            $this->insertAt('</ul>',$group_end + $offset);
            $offset += 5;
        }
    }

    private function insertAt($str,$index){
        $this->html = substr($this->html,0,$index) . $str . substr($this->html,$index);
    }

    private function isSeperating($str){
        return preg_match("/\w/", $str);
    }
}
```

Change the `isSeparating()` function to your needs. It gets passed the text between each `li` tag and returns true if it separates the `li`s. Currently it checks if there is any character other than whitespace (line-break, tabs, etc).

Use it like this:

```
$output = (new LiFormatter($input))->html;
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex? **Yes please!**

You can port that to PHP if you want to. Just for demonstration purposes in JS.

```js
var response = "Some text <strong>Some other text</strong><li>Element A1</li><li>Element A2</li><li>Element A3</li>Text that separates group A from group B<li>Element B1</li><li>Element B2</li> <li>Element B3</li><li>Element B4</li><strong>Element that separates group B from group C</strong><li>Element C1</li><li>Element C2</li>Text can follow.";

var r = response.replace(/(?<!<\/li>\s*)<li>/g,'<ul><li>'); // <ul>
var r = r.replace(/<\/li>(?!\s*<li>)/g,'</li></ul>'); // <ul>
$('#result').html(r);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='result'></div>
```

Comment: Thank you. That's more or less the solution I've already had :)